How to send Unicode in a USB HID report?
There's a question with almost an exact name name. The answer states that for (general) Unicode characters his solution was OS-dependent.
However, the HID Usage Tables 1.5 doc has a dedicated Usage Page for Unicode, namely, Unicode Page (0x10), which states
The Unicode Page directly maps to the two-octet form defined in the Unicode Standard.

The Unicode Standard, Version 1.1, is the newest version of the Unicode™ Standard. Unicode 1.1 includes the changes and
additions that were made to Unicode 1.0 in the process of alignment with the international character encoding standard,
ISO/IEC 10646-1, which was approved by ISO/IEC as an International Standard in June 1992, and published in May
1993. The character content and encoding of Unicode 1.1 is thus identical to that of the ISO/IEC 10646-1 UCS-2 (the
two-octet form).

from which I understand that there's an OS-independent solution, ie. that you can send raw Unicode encoded as 16 bits (aka. UCS-2?).

In that case, how would an 8-byte USB HID Report look like for general Unicode characters?

For example, if I want to send a single letter lowercase a keypress from a USB HID device (eg. a keyboard) to a USB HID host (eg. a PC), I can do:
uint8_t hid_report[0x08];
hid_report[0x00] = 0b00000000;
hid_report[0x01] = 0x00;
hid_report[0x02] = 0x04;
hid_report[0x03] = 0x00;
hid_report[0x04] = 0x00;
hid_report[0x05] = 0x00;
hid_report[0x06] = 0x00;
hid_report[0x07] = 0x00;

and it works (ie. the USB HID host driver recognizes the keypress).
Now, I think that the host driver's interpretation of USB HID Reports depends on the USB HID Report Descriptor that the device sends to the host, which in this case was:
0x05,0x01,       // Usage Page: Generic Desktop Page (0x01), page HID Usage Tables 1.4
0x09,0x06,       // Usage:      Keyboard (0x06)
0xa1,0x01,       // Collection: Application
    0x05,0x07,       // Usage Page:      Keyboard/Keypad Page (0x07)
    0x19,0xe0,       // Usage Minimum:   0xe0: kbd lctrl
    0x29,0xe7,       // Usage Maximum:   0xe7: kbd rgui
    0x15,0x00,       // Logical Minimum: 0
    0x25,0x01,       // Logical Maximum: 1

    0x95,0x08,       // Report Count:    8  // 8 keys? mod mask
    0x75,0x01,       // Report Size:     1  // 1 bit each?
    0x81,0x02,       // Input:           Data,Var, Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position

    0x95,0x01,       // Report Count:    1  // 1 key? pad
    0x75,0x08,       // Report Size:     8  // 8 bits each?
    0x81,0x03,       // Input:           Const,Var, Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position

    0x05,0x07,       // Usage Page:      Kbrd/Keypad
    0x19,0x00,       // Usage Minimum
    0x29,0xff,       // Usage Maximum  // 0x65 is the max for a boot device?
    0x15,0x00,       // Logical Minimum
    0x26,0xff,0x00,  // Logical Maximum  // 0x65 is the max for a boot device?  // 0x25: int8? 0x26: int16?

    0x95,0x06,       // Report Count:    6  // 6 keys? 6 keys (6KRO)
    0x75,0x08,       // Report Size:     8  // 8 bits each?
    0x81,0x00,       // Input:           Data,Array, Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position
0xc0,            // End Collection

but I think it's possible to use completely different binary layouts for a USB HID keypress/keyrelease report, like, for example, a large bitmask, where each key in the keyboard corresponds to 1 bit in the USB HID Report. In that case, the report descriptor for Unicode characters would also change. So, how to send 16-bit-encoded Unicode characters in the bitmask USB HID report as well?
(Notice that this USB HID report already includes a bitmask representation for the first 8 bits; ie. the modifiers are encoded as an 8-bit bitmask.)
Bonus question: how to send Unicode characters that UCS-2 can't encode?

Let me share my thoughts on your problem.
Keyboard Usage Page
The USB HID Report Descriptor of your device shows two different Keyboard Usage Pages (0x07).
The first page is for Usage IDs 0xe0 to 0xe7, which will represent eight control keys. The device can send all 8 of them at the same time. Possible values for EACH key: 0 or 1 (2 values, one bit).
The second page is for Usage IDs 0x00 to 0xff, which will represent 256 "normal" keys. The device can send just 6 of them at the same time (6KRO). Possible values for these keys (the usage type is "Selector", the value is the ID): 0x00 to 0x00ff (256 values, eight bits).
Note 1: for the second page, the descriptor is using a 16-bit value for the "Logical Maximum" (using tag 0x26), but the actual data is still constrained to 256 values, and the "Report Size" is just 8 bits.
Note 2: the Usage IDs 0xe0 to 0xe7 are present in both pages. I understand the first page takes precedence for this range (ie. these eight codes are to be interpreted as bitmaps for control keys, and not as keycodes).
Note 3: for the second page, each of the 256 values represent a key position, labeled in the specification as the character which is at that position in a US keyboard. (Local keyboard "reinterpretations", if necessary, are done at the host.)
Unicode Usage Page
The Unicode Usage Page is completely different, and it just sends 16-bit values, which are to be interpreted as UCS-2 encoded characters (the old, restricted form of 16-bit Unicode). If your host system "understands" UCS-2, then this should work smoothly.
But your device, according to what you posted, doesn't support the Unicode Usage Page.
A custom Usage Page
You could define your own usage page, on the device, for encoding any kind of data in any way you like. Of course, your host should understand this custom code page. (Other hosts must just ignore it.)
But, there is one limitation. Section 3.1 of the "HID Usage Tables" (version 1.5) clearly says:

Usage ID values are limited to 16 bits

So, even with your own page/encoding, you couldn't identify more than 2^16 separate character/entities. At least in one single page.
And about the possibility of using a very long bitmap for sending a lot of (at most 2^16).characters  at the same time, I think that would probably surpass another limit in the specification.

Yes, the device I showed doesn't support Unicode; it's just the Keybord\Keypad Page (0x07). I'm asking what a device that supports the Unicode Page (0x10) would look like in a way that the USB HID host driver understands (without me having to write my own host-side driver).

If I'm not wrong, the device will just report UCS-2 (always 16-bit) codes, just as the keyboard usage page reports 8-bit key positions (and key modifiers).

Note that these are not current Unicode UTF-16 codes (16/32-bit variable size codes).
